# In react native, calling a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbee, I sorry all if my question is wrong

This is a code, I refer React tutorial:

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(createUser)} className={classes.form}>
```

I wanna ask that:

1. Why my they used a inline Arrow Function ?
2. And what happen i cannot use to use it ?

Comment: "Why my they used a inline Arrow Function ?" So they could set a parameter. "And what happen i cannot use to use it ?" You can

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Sub Question Answer:

Inline Arrow Function is created on render because the function definition is inside of the onClick handler, which is inside of the component render method (or return, in the case of functional React components).

You’d use an inline function to pass in additional arguments to a function, such as a value from a loop, or the target button’s value.

Let’s take a look at an example:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => alert('hello'))}>
      Click me!
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2 Sub Question Answer:
You can use to use it. You can take a look at different ways you can do the onClick Event Handling [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onclick-event-handling-with-examples)

Comment: welcome, if my answer helped you then pls upvote it. @victhangnguyen

Answer (score 0):

The 'anonym/arrow-function' function is for pass the reference of the function, and that reference react will call when detect the event. Is like variable storage

If you cant use it, you can pass a reference of a normal function

```
const handleSubmit = (...args) =>  {}
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.form}>
```

the args will get all event parameters of anything that event handle